# Multiple comparisons of Box-Cox transformed data

Tags: data-transformation, multiple-comparisons, boxcox-transformation

I'm working on a dataset of highly-skewed data that I have transformed using Box-Cox. I have 2 groups (healthy controls and diseased participants) and I need to perform multiple comparisons (to compare the two groups across different frequency bands). Within each comparison, I am using the same lambda for the Box-Cox transformation (so both groups are equally transformed for the same frequency), but ideally, lambda would vary across frequencies (because for some frequencies the data is more skewed than for others). Is this correct? Can I proceed with multiple comparisons correction over the p-values of my data transformed with different lambda values? I have tried to find a common value of lambda but failed so far.

Comment: "*ideally, lambda would vary across frequencies (because for some frequencies the data is more skewed than for others)*" - You're operating under a false premise. Having the same skewness does not imply the same transformation will make both symmetric - equivalently, using the same transformation on two random variables whose distributions have exactly the same skewness may symmetrize one but not the other.  Neither does having different skewness imply that different $\lambda$s would be needed. Two distributions with very different skewnesses can be made symmetric with the same transformation

Comment: It can easily be the case that a stronger transformation is needed to symmetrize a distribution with smaller skewness. It's also possible to have very simple-form distributions that cannot be symmetrized by a power transformation.

Comment: You are right. Regardless, the optimal lambda values obtained for each frequency (using Matlab's boxcox) are different.